# how to insert into database columns one after the other using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have three columns that I want to insert data into using php. the code will be run three times.

I want if run the code the first time to insert only on **column1** while leaving other columns empty.

If run the second time to insert into only **column2** while leaving other column empty

and so on. I have tried the code below but cannot get it to work. it only inserts into the column1

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include('db.php');

$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM rec');
$result->execute(array());
while ($row = $result->fetch()) 
{
    //$id = $row['id'];
    $column1 = $row['column1'];
    $column2 = $row['column2'];
    $column3 = $row['column3'];
}


if ($column1 ==''){
    echo 'empty'; 

    $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO rec(column1)
                                values(:column1)');

    $statement->execute(array(':column1' =>'$column1'));
} elseif ($column2 ==''){
    echo 'empty2';  

    $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO rec (column2)
                                values(:column2)');

    $statement->execute(array(':column2' =>'$column2'));
} elseif ($column3==''){
    echo 'empty3';  

    $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO rec(column3)
                                values(:column3)');
    $statement->execute(array(':column3' =>'$column3'));

}
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Seems like a bad table design if you're performing inserts like this with mostly null values.

Comment: _I know I will regret this but_ How many rows are there in the `rec` table

Comment: Obvious error `$statement->execute(array(':column1' =>'$column1'));` try without the quotes `$statement->execute(array(':column1' =>$column1));`

Comment: **Dont you mean UPDATE and not INSERT**

Comment: **Also** You only run the IF if `$column1` is empty. Then you try and INSERT another row with `$column1` as the data which is of course empty ??????? I definitely dont get what you are trying to do here

Comment: The more I look at this code the less it makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if-else is such that the correct data is not getting inserted properly . Use the following code which will solve your purpose in your way . However , the way you are following is not correct . Either you follow the conventional way to create a database and inserting values into it or use dynamic fields for a table and insert it another way .

```
if ($column1 ==''){
    echo 'empty';
}

else{

    $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO rec(column1)
                            values(:column1)');

    $statement->execute(array(':column1' =>'$column1'));

} 

if ($column2 ==''){
    echo 'empty2';
}

else{ 

    $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO rec (column2)
                            values(:column2)');

    $statement->execute(array(':column2' =>'$column2'));

} 

if ($column3==''){
    echo 'empty3';
}

else{

    $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO rec(column3)
                            values(:column3)');
    $statement->execute(array(':column3' =>'$column3'));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it is not a proper way of designing database.

Secondly, use if statements only rather than nested if-else statements and it will work!

Comment: I have upvoted you because what you have said is correct .